# Height of span inside hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, hidden

I need to get the height of span inside a hidden element with jquery. I already tried a few things, including change the css of my div to 'position':'absolute','visibility':'hidden','display':'block' and making a clone of the whole thing but nothing worked. Not even the [jquery actual plugin](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/)

I made a simplified example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5XreY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set only visibility to hidden, and then measure it. http://jsfiddle.net/5XreY/1/ Element won't be visible, but will be measurable and if you want it to be display: none you can set this right after you measure its height.

Comment: Of course it will still take up "space" on the page if you do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

To get the accurate size of an element it needs to be rendered (i.e not hidden). One trick is to move it off-screen to measure it using a negative text-indent or absolute positioning.